# Microsoft graph api - no refresh_token

Tags: rest, access-token, extend, microsoft-graph-api, refresh-token

i want to use MS graph api, i have CODE, and i need to exchange code for access token, when i post request, like in [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/get-started/rest) i get this answer

```
{
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": "mail.read mail.send user.read user.read.all",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "ext_expires_in": 0,
  "access_token": "blah blah blah ..... §§&&##"
}
```

and this token will expire in 1 hour, i found, that i need `refresh_token` to extend token next time, but i havent got any **in response with access_token**

any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [Active Directory Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-tokens), you need to request the `offline_access` scope in your authorization code request and your token request.

Comment: when i add scope=offline_access webpage show error says 
Log in
There was a problem trying to sign in.
We received a bad request.
url is: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<myAppID-replaced>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login&response_type=code&scope=offline_access

Comment: sorry, my bad, now i managed to work and i have refresh_token, thanks

Comment: @LubošZápotočný how did you get the refresh token. I am currently using the microsoft authentication library and it says that it does not return refresh tokens. Did you write your code from scratch or is there a hack in the library. A link to your github would be appreciated if you do not remember and it's not a commercial project.

Comment: @RahmiPruitt I am sorry, i do not have access to that code anymore. Anyway, I remember creating that request body by myself - no library.
Can you provide link to your library?
Also have a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user#token-request